# Find List2 in List1 at starting Position

Tags: python, list, list-comparison

```
List1 = ['RELEASE', 'KM123', 'MOTOR', 'XS4501', 'NAME']

List2 = ['KM', 'XS', 'M']
```

Now I am using code that only searches List2 in List1 in any position.

```
Result = [ s for s in List1 if any(xs in s for xs in List2]
```

Output :

```
[KM123', 'MOTOR', 'XS4501', 'NAME']
```

But I don't want 'NAME' to be in the list because it contains 'M' not in the starting. Any help...

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.startswith()` which checks if a string starts with a particular  sequence of characters:

```
[s for s in List1 if any(s.startswith(xs) for xs in List2)]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: Can we also check after List1 contains List2 followed by numbers i.e result only contains 'KM123', 'XS4501'

Comment: This question is answered. Can you ask a new question to avoid confusion to future readers of this post and then, if you ping me , I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `str.startswith`

**Ex:**

```
List1 = ['RELEASE', 'KM123', 'MOTOR', 'XS4501', 'NAME']
List2 = ('KM', 'XS', 'M')                                 #convert to tuple
result = [ s for s in List1 if s.startswith(List2)]
print(result)   #-->['KM123', 'MOTOR', 'XS4501']
```

Comment: I dislike the semantics of this: a string starts with a tuple... Why should a string start with a tuple?

Comment: @ThomasWeller using a tuple you can check for multiple strings instead of looping and checking each. Ex `s.startswith(('KM', 'XS', 'M') )`